# Twig and Yii How to call registerScriptFile from a .twig template

Tags: yii, twig

I would like to use Yii's registerCSSFile and registerScriptFile from inside a *.twig view element. Calling the scripts from the controller like this:

```
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl;
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/yourscript.js');
$cs->registerScriptFile('/js/otherscript.js', CClientScript::POS_END);
```

works fine, but I feel that CSS and JS requirements should (ideally) be called from a view.

I was hoping something like

```
{% set cs = App.getClientScript %}
{{ cs.registerScriptFile('/path/to/js/yourscript.js') }}
```

but unfortunately it won't parse under Twig. Can anyone offer assistance?

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I'd like to load the JS and CSS Files from the "Twig" View instead of the Controller as I am currently

Answer (score 0):

Check out this extension:

https://github.com/yiiext/twig-renderer

Clienscript eample:

`{{void(App.clientScript.registerScriptFile(...))}}`